# IceCast 2.3.2+ chunk encoding MP3 streams

Tags: android, encoding, streaming, icecast, chunked

Does anyone host IceCast 2.3.2+ server with chunk encoding MP3 stream, that I can test?
I'd like to test it whether would be any stream stops caused of small chunk length in Android Mediaplayer.

Comment: why don't you try on icecast mailing list.

Comment: I asked some questions there, but received no big help.

Comment: The fact that you're using chunked encoding at all will break many Android players.  The chunk length itself has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: But the app can work for hours without error. Sometimes it suddenly happens. I saw the similar problem with MediaPlayer in the Web, where were small chunks, that can cause stops. In WireShark there is a stop when a TCP segment data comes to 5 bytes instead of ~1000. Why? Isn't MediaPlayer compatible with chunked encoding? Any official info from Google?

Comment: Also, this happens in other players in many Windows browsers.

Comment: UPDATE: without chunk encoding the stream stop happens too, rarely.

Answer (score 1):

Icecast up to and including version 2.4.1 does not support HTTP chunked encoding at all. Version 2.5.0 will support chunked encoding for HTTP PUT requests (source client side), but there is currently no point in supporting it for GET requests.

You might have confused this with the metadata hack introduced by Shoutcast for MP3 streams. There the actual encoded audio data stream is interrupted at a fixed, so called, *metadata-interval* and metadata is injected.

A player that is capable of handling such a stream has to signal this to the server through a HTTP header and if supported the streaming server will inform the client in the response HTTP headers about the metadata-interval and other parameters. The player then **must** remove this injected data from the stream upon reception and before handing it to a decoder for playback.

Please note that this hack is only necessary for streams that don't have a container with inherent metadata handling. Opus and Ogg/Vorbis streams will send the metadata natively inside the stream without need for such hacks.